# Objective-C equivalent for java byte[]

Tags: objective-c

In Java, I would pass bytes around as byte[] which also knows it's own length.
is there an equivalent array in Objective C?

I'm not sure, but NSArray seems too heavy weight for something like that as it can hold any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest thing is `NSMutableData` and its `mutableBytes` property. That'll give you a C style array with a length count attached. The only slight complexity is that while you can read and modify entries by mutableBytes, you need to use `appendBytes:length:` to add extra bytes onto the end should you want the buffer to grow.

Answer (score 0):

I think Tommy has the correct answer, but it's worth noting that you can also use the primitive C data types (i.e., `char*` in this case). When things get very low level -- as might be the case when you're talking about individual bytes -- avoiding some of the cleverer stuff may perform better.

Comment: I would agree; recently I needed to keep track of a large array of `BOOL` values representing pixel locations, and found that having a two dimensional array of bytes was significantly faster than using `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` for the same purpose.

Comment: And you can wrap them in NSValue

Answer (score 0):

I also think @Tommy has the correct answer, but it's also worth considering that the built in storage classes are heavily optimized. Unless you are confident that performance will be an issue, it may be easier to use NSMutableArray and only move away after you've shown that you're having performance issues. If you need to store primitive values, take a look at [CFMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: I don't think NSMutableArray is suitable for storing arrays of byte values.  Each byte would have to be wrapped in an NSValue in order to go into the array.  NSData or NSMutableData is the right thing here.