# Java Data Type Equivalent to Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, ios

What are the equivalent for this Java data type in Objective-C

short[] data;
byte[] data;
char[] Array;
LinkedList< byte[] > varName
LinkedList< short[] > varName;

I'm new on this, I'll apreciate your help.

Thank You.

Comment: Trying to convert Java -> Objective-C as a line-by-line coding exercise is destined to failure.  You need to start with the architecture, understand the targets platform's architecture and then figure out how to effectively map your app onto that (at which point, questions like these will almost assuredly not come up at all).

Answer (score 0):

see: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_2.0_Data_Types
**short array is supported**

```
short[] data; //works
```

see: [Objective-C equivalent for java byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244907/objective-c-byte-array-type)
and: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html
**byte array alternative**

```
NSString *myString = @"string for data1";
const char *utfMyString = [myString UTF8String];
NSMutableData *data1 = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:utfMyString length:strlen(utfMyString)+1];
```

see: [Byte array in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876598/byte-array-in-objective-c)
**char array is supported**

```
char byteArray[] = {0x12,0x13,0x53}; //works
```

**LinkedList is not supported**
I found some alternative on CocoaDev, read more here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?LinkedList
and also read this, I think too that you don't always need to use LinkedList solution:  [Creating Linked Lists in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262223/creating-linked-lists-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

The first few examples are basically the same in Objective-C, with a few reservations:

```
short data[] = {...};
byte data[] = {...};
char data[] = {...};
```

The reservation is that *these are not dynamic arrays*. The compiler needs to know their sizes; that is, if you use the `T arr[]` notation, you need to immediately assign a value to it. Otherwise, explicitly specify its size (as in `T arr[1000]`). You also have the option of representing these as pointers (`T* arr`).

In Objective-C, we usually like to have a greater level of flexibility than plain C arrays will give us, so we use `NSArray` for similar tasks frequently. Please check out the [documentation on `NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) if you haven't already done so.

As for the linked lists, Cocoa doesn't have a built-in linked list implementation. It's rare that you'll actually end up using a linked list in Objective-C idiom, but if you need it, it's really quite easy to implement. Be aware that Objective-C does *not* have parametric polymorphism; thus, you cannot generalize a type over other types, as would be necessary for `LinkedList` to hold values of various types. And since primitives can't be cast to objects coherently, you can't create a generic `LinkedList` class that can hold primitives or objects (you can unify primitives under `void*`, but not objects, since they require memory management).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an array of integers. Just change it to be short or char.

[Create an array of integers property in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476843/create-an-array-of-integers-property-in-objective-c)